# Processed batch vs RDD in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

I saw several answers(e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438168/difference-between-rdds-and-batches-in-spark)) in SO suggest that records in a batch will become a single RDD. I doubt it because suppose a batchInterval is 1 minute, then a single RDD will contain all data from last minute?

NOTE: I'm not directly comparing batch to RDD but rather the batch processed by Spark internally.

Answer (score 1):

Let me quote [Spark Streaming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#discretized-streams-dstreams)

> Discretized Stream or DStream is the basic abstraction provided by Spark Streaming. It represents a continuous stream of data, either the input data stream received from source, or the processed data stream generated by transforming the input stream. Internally, a DStream is represented by a continuous series of RDDs, which is Spark’s abstraction of an immutable, distributed dataset (see Spark Programming Guide for more details). Each RDD in a DStream contains data from a certain interval, as shown in the following figure.

[image]

As you can see -  single batch = single RDD. This is why adjusting batch interval depending on your the data flow is crucial for the stability of your application.